# Converting an enum where all variants implement the same trait to a box in Rust?

Tags: enums, rust, traits

I have a trait `Foo`, with some implementations, together with an enum `Foos` with one variant per implemention. I want to be able to convert my enum into `Box<dyn Foo>`.

This is my current solution:

```
trait Foo {}

struct FooA {}
impl Foo for FooA {}

struct FooB {}
impl Foo for FooB {} 

struct FooC {}
impl Foo for FooC {}

enum Foos {
    A(FooA),
    B(FooB),
    C(FooC),
}

impl Foos {
    fn into_box(self) -> Box<dyn Foo> {
        match self {
            Foos::A(foo) => Box::new(foo),
            Foos::B(foo) => Box::new(foo),
            Foos::C(foo) => Box::new(foo),
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but there's a lot of boiler plate in `into_enum`. As the number of variants grow, so will the function. Is there a simpler way to do this? It feels like it should be a one liner!

Comment: "It feels like it should be a one liner!" primary opinion ? If you want you can create RFC for Rust.

Comment: Also, why not `impl Foo for Foos` ?

Comment: @Stargateur `Foo` has many methods and I don't want to have to do a match over the enum variants for every one of them.

Comment: yeah I think there is a keyword in preparation for this, still a macro could do the job very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the [`enum_dispatch` crate](https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/0.1.2/enum_dispatch/), you can write

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate enum_dispatch;

#[enum_dispatch]
trait Foo {}

struct FooA {}
impl Foo for FooA {}

struct FooB {}
impl Foo for FooB {}

struct FooC {}
impl Foo for FooC {}

#[enum_dispatch(Foo)]
enum Foos {
    A(FooA),
    B(FooB),
    C(FooC),
}
```

to get a generated `impl Foo for Foos`. You can then convert `Foos` to `Box<dyn Foo>` with simply `Box::new`.

There is a potential downside to this approach: `Box::new(Foos::A(FooA))` contains a `Foos`, not an `FooA`, so it will incur the overhead of both the dynamic dispatch from `dyn Foo` to `Foos` and the `enum` dispatch from `Foos` to `FooA`.

On the other hand, now that you have `impl Foo for Foos`: everywhere you would have used `Box<dyn Foo>`, you’ll instead be able to directly use `Foos`, which should be more efficient in every way.

Answer (score 5):

I recently wanted something similar. I cannot offer you a one-liner, but a macro that automatically generates the respective `match` arms along with then `enum` variants:

```
macro_rules! impl_foos{($($enumvariant: ident($foo: ty),)*) => {
    enum Foos {
        $($enumvariant($foo),)*
    }
    impl Foos {
        fn into_enum(self) -> Box<dyn Foo> {
            match self {
                $(Foos::$enumvariant(foo) => Box::new(foo),)*
            }
        }
    }
}}

impl_foos!(
    A(FooA),
    B(FooB),
    C(FooC),
);
```

This way, there is only one place to maintain all the possibilities, everything else is generated. Maybe even the [crate enum_dispatch](https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/0.1.2/enum_dispatch/) helps.

Off-topic: Should it really be `into_enum(self)->Box<dyn Foo>`? Shouldn't it be something like `as_foo(&self)->&dyn Foo`?

Comment: Sorry, `into_enum` was meant to be `into_box`, my bad. I have updated the question. Intersting that you can return `&dyn`, I did not know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to convert from enum to trait, and then Box that.  Yes a bit boilerplate, but not as much as posted, reusable, and your IDE should create all the arms.

```rust
trait MyTrait {
}

enum MyEnum {
  Var1(SomeTraitStruct),
  Var2(AnotherTraitStruct),
}

impl MyEnum {
    fn to_my_trait(&self) -> &dyn MyTrait {
        match self {
            MyEnum::Var1(it) => { it }
            MyEnum::Var2(it) => { it }
        }
    }
}

fn test() {
  let value = MyEnum::Var1(SomeTraitStruct{})
  let my_trait = value.to_my_trait();
  let my_box:Box<&dyn MyTrait> = Box::new(my_trait); 
}
```