# Is it possible to extract the underlying enum value object in Rust without match?

Tags: rust, enums, casting, traits

Given enum values implement the same trait, is it possible to extract trait object from enum value?

Form the [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html) example:

```
fn main() {
    enum IpAddr {
        V4(String),
        V6(String),
    }

    let home = IpAddr::V4(String::from("127.0.0.1"));

    let loopback = IpAddr::V6(String::from("::1"));
}
```

Here all the enum values hold a `String`, is it possible to extract it without enumerating all the options with `match`?

Something like:

```
   let result = factory.get_enum(); // -> IpAddr
   let str: String = (some_cast)result.getValue();
```

I'd like to avoid:

```
    match result {
       Product1(product1) => {},
       ...
       ProductN(productN) => {}
    }
```

And more complicated case: let's say all the enum values hold a trait object:

```
trait TProduct {
   fn something();
}

impl TProduct for Product1 {}
...
impl TProduct for ProductN {}

enum ProductResult {
  product1(Product1),
  ..
  productN(ProductN)
}

...

let result: ProductResult = factory.build();
let product = result.getValue() as dyn TProduct; // is it possible with Rust?
let something = product.something();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read from an enum without pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473656/read-from-an-enum-without-pattern-matching) Or perhaps this? [Converting an enum where all variants implement the same trait to a box in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056660/converting-an-enum-where-all-variants-implement-the-same-trait-to-a-box-in-rust)

Comment: Implement such method for `IpAddr` or `ProductResult` and use the method. Or use a crate that implemented it for you (see links given by kmdreko)

Comment: Does it meat `match` will be just inside of `IpAddr.something()`? With "enum_dispatch: create it seems to be conceptually the same, but just without manual typing.

Comment: I think the answer to the titular question is just "no". The idea behind enum is that it contains *different* values with different types and meanings. If you really have a value that is common in type and meaning, you should use a `struct` instead and make it a field: `enum AddrType { V4, V6 }; struct IPAddr { type: AddrType, raw_addr: String }`.

Comment: fair enough. However keeping it in the same structure can be undesired/impossible if it's different trait objects with different fieldsset

Comment: If all your enum variants implement the same trait, consider using a trait object like `Box<dyn Trait>` instead of the enum.

Comment: @SvenMarnach that's the original problem - how to cast it to concrete trait impl later (without using `as_any` trick)?

Comment: Are you referring to mplementing an `as_any()` method on the trait? That's a common solution for downcasting trait objects. Why are you ruling it out? Another solution is the [downcast_rs crate](https://docs.rs/downcast-rs/1.2.0/downcast_rs/).

Comment: @SvenMarnach I can be wrong but i had a feeling that `as_any` is not a Rust canonical way but rather a trick. Thanks for suggesting `downcast_rs` crate

Comment: I'm not sure it's the "canonical" way, but it's definitely a perfectly fine approach, and there is nothing wrong with it. The `downcast_rs` crate does the same – it's just a bit more convenient.